# Is it possible to use Vuetify's date picker with an array from vuex as its v-model?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm trying to map a component holding a form to variables in vuex, under an object named "displayedFarmer".

`displayedFarmer` has `arrivalDates` as an array.

I'm using `mapState` to bring in `displayedFarmer`:

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['displayedFarmer']),
```

I'm using the data picker as such:

```
<v-date-picker
   v-model="displayedFarmer.arrivalDates"
   :disabled="isDisabled"
   multiple
   >
</v-date-picker>
```

If I'm using `dates` - an array initialized in the vue `data()` function, it works as expected. But directly to the `displayedFarmer.arrivalDates` - it doesn't work at all.

I've tried using `dates` and then placing a watch on it to sync it manually - but this is just a dirty hack and it causes reactivity issues in the entire component.

Is there a way to v-model directly to my vuex variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. OK first of all never do this `v-model="displayedFarmer.arrivalDates"` if `displayedFarmer` is your state in Vuex. You will mutate it directly which is a bad practice.
2. Try using computed value with `get` and `set` into `v-model`. It goes like this:

```
// template
- v-model="displayedFarmer.arrivalDates" // delete this line
+ v-model="arrivalDatesProxy" // add this line
```

```
// script
computed: {
  ...mapState(['displayedFarmer']),
  arrivalDatesProxy: {
    get() {
      return this.displayedFarmer.arrivalDates;
    },
    set(newValue) {
      // here you commit mutation to change the state with newValue
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: This is actually very close to what I ended up doing! The only difference, that in my `get()` function I had to add a condition in case the `arrivalDates` is `undefined`, since from some reason, even though I initialized it, it came back as `undefined` the first time it was accessed, causing an error in the `v-date-picker` component

Comment: Hard to say why you have an `undefined`, maybe there is something wrong with your architecture, don't know ‍♂️ But you can always put `v-if` on a component in case `arrivalDates` is `undefined`  Glad you got it working 

Comment: oh yes, I finally figured it out - I was dispatching an action called `resetDisplayedFarmer` in the `created()` function of the parent component - that explains it ;-P

Comment: There you go! aah debugging, pain in the a...  

Answer (score 0):

`v-model` is shorthand for a combination of `:value` and `@input`.
Since vuex data should only be changed using `commit`, you can use the "longhand" to update the value.

```
<v-date-picker
   :value="displayedFarmer.arrivalDates"
   @input="updateArrivalDates"
   :disabled="isDisabled"
   multiple
   >
</v-date-picker>
```

Where `updateArrivalDates` either dispatches an action or commits a vuex change.

Comment: Tried that. It doesn't work - the date picker seems to not be getting the new values. When I choose a date, I see in the vue debug tools (vuex tab) that the `displayedFarmer.arrivalDates` have been updated, but the date picker doesn't seem to get the message from some reason

Comment: One more thing, I suspect it has something to do with the fact that `arrivalDates` is nested in `displayedFarmer` - when I create a `dates` array in vuex, and do the same, it works as expected, no weird reactivity issues