# Vuex: Why do nested objects stay undefined, even when initialized in the state?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm defining my state with an object, initialized with some nested objects to an empty string and an empty array, as such:

```js
state: {
  displayedFarmer: {
    name: "",
    arrivalDates: []
    // some more fields...
  },
  // more vuex stuff
}
```

I would expect that if I `console.log` the displayed farmer, `arrivalDates` would appear. Here's what I did to track it in my component:

```js
  computed: {
    ...mapState([ 'displayedFarmer' ]),
    // more code
  },
  watch: {
    displayedFarmer: {
      handler() {
        console.log("displayedFarmer", this.displayedFarmer);
      },
      deep: true,
      immediate: true
    }
  }
```

The first log line appearing shows the `displayedFarmer` object, with the `arrivalDates` and name missing:

```
displayedFarmer 
Object { … }
```

(basically only the `prototype` and the `__ob__` objects appear when I expand it in the console)

That behavior is unclear to me, and has forced me to use a small and harmless hack to initialize  the fields the first time they are being accessed.

For this question, what I want to know is:

1. Why can't I see the objects I initialized in my state when I access them via the component?
2. How can I do this differently, so that when I first access the object, all the nested items are initialized?

Comment: Unless you modified `displayedFarmer` at all, what you logged should be the same object with those properties as you defined in the initial state. Something else is going on. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: The props you mention appear fine in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-sanderson-84xts?file=/src/components/Demo.vue)

Comment: @tony19 - after looking at your demo, I dug into my code further and found that in the parent component I'm dispatching an action to clear the `displayedFarmer` object. Oh, silly me!

Answer (score 0):

1. `watch` with `immediate: true` fires before components `hook:created`. This is probably the reason you don't have access to the initialized object.
2. I don't know what you are trying to achieve, can you expand your question?
3. The first thing that came to my mind is to try to call `method` (which does whatever you want) on a `hook:mouted`. Then call the same method in watcher, but with `immediate: false` (which is a default btw)

Comment: For the scope of this question, the only thing I want to achieve is to understand why I don't see the object with all its nested objects. But since you asked, this is a continuation of another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491939/is-it-possible-to-use-vuetifys-date-picker-with-an-array-from-vuex-as-its-v-mod/64492442) where I'm trying to use vuetify date picker with vuex. The main issue being, that the date picker won't mount if I give it a v-model (or bind a value) that is not an array. The watch in my question is just a debug tool, not what I'm trying to achieve